# Filter checked checkboxes

Tags: qtableview, pyqt6, qsortfilterproxymodel, qabstracttablemodel

By this I tried to make a minimal reproducible example of what I now have.
Using QSortFilterProxyModel() to find text and a custom SortFilterProxyModel to show all the selected checkboxes.

It looks like both proxy's conflicting eachother and giving the wrong row number back. (There is also an option for adding value with a dialog and also this goes to the wrong row with the custom proxy enabled, but works without the custom proxy).

```
class winConfigurator(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, data=None):
        super(winConfigurator,self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'winConfiguratorView.ui'), self)

        self.leSearch.returnPressed.connect(self.searchField)
        self.chMatchSelected.toggled.connect(self.showSelected)
        
    def readFile(self, filename):
        self.model = TableModel([headers, newRows])

        self.proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.model)
        
        """
        Proxy for 'Show Selected'
        """
        self.custom_proxy_model = SortFilterProxyModel()
        self.custom_proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.proxy_model)

        self.tableView.setModel(self.custom_proxy_model)

    def searchField(self):
        self.proxy_model.setFilterFixedString(self.leSearch.text())
    
    def showSelected(self, state = None):
        self.custom_proxy_model.clearFilter()
        checkstate_items = self.model.checks.items()
        if state == True:
            self.custom_proxy_model.setFilterByCheckbox(checkstate_items)

class SortFilterProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QSortFilterProxyModel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.filters = {}

    def setFilterByCheckbox(self, checkstates = {}):
        self.filters = checkstates
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def clearFilter(self):
        self.filters = {}
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
        """
        Check if checkbox is checked and show this row
        Slow, 7 seconds for 50k rows.
        """
        try:
            values = []
            if self.filters:
                for index, is_checked in self.filters:
                    if is_checked:
                        row = index.row()
                        model = self.sourceModel()
                        if hasattr(model, 'mapToSource'):
                            index = model.index(source_row, 0, source_parent)
                            if not index.parent().isValid():
                                modelIndex = model.mapToSource(index)
                                source_row = modelIndex.row()
                                
                        if row == source_row:
                            values.append(index)
                return any(values)
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            # print(e)
            return True
```

Comment: I'm afraid you're misunderstanding how the filter mode works: if you want custom behavior, *you* must implement `filterAcceptsRow` and eventually return false/true depending on the value in the source model.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to make a class like class SortFilterProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel)
But I also use QSortFilterProxyModel for filtering and searching in the table (See in my first post) and that's not working then anymore.
I really don't know how to implement this filteracceptsrow for the checkboxes.

Comment: I know it's difficult but can someone help me explaining how to do this?

What I now have: 
`self.custom_proxy_model = SortFilterProxyModel()`
`self.chMatchSelected.toggled.connect(self.custom_proxy_model.filterAcceptsRow)`

`class SortFilterProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):`
`def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):`
`QSortFilterProxyModel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`
`def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row = 0, source_parent = QModelIndex):`
`print(f'State {source_row}')`
`return False`
But it does nothing.

Comment: As already said, filterAcceptsRow returns false *OR* true based on the condition, as explained in [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterAcceptsRow). If you always return `False`, it becomes useless. Your override should then check *both* cases: if the default implementation (`super().filterAcceptsRow(row, parent)`) `and` the check state of the source index model are true.

Comment: Sorry I was really confused by trying to use filterAcceptsRow, but this function is running itself by using the class. I have a working demo and trying to add it to my main app. Now I have two models and merged it.
`self.model = TableModel([headers, newRows])
self.custom_proxy_model = SortFilterProxyModel()
self.proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel()
self.proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.model)
self.custom_proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.proxy_model)
self.tableView.setModel(self.custom_proxy_model)`

Next thing is that the source_row is incorrect, but there is no map_to_source.

Comment: I did it! I found out there is a self.sourceModel() that had the right attributes. Next thing was to get the right index. But finally I have a working filterAcceptsRow. I post the code in the first post.

Comment: Glad you solved it, but please don't write the solution in the question. Use the answer field for it, that's its purpose.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see an answer field. Sadly it's not solved. Still getting the wrong row number. Look likes self.sourceModel() get's the wrong model (proxy_model instead of custom_proxy_model) If I changes the setModel/setSourceModels one or both models not working anymore. Second is the function a bit slow. 7 seconds for 50k rows.

Comment: Well, for starters, checking *all* filters *every time* is wrong: as soon as you find a match, you should just return `True`, there's no point in keep checking the other filters. Then, I don't know what arguments you use for `setFilterByCheckbox`, but you're probably using the wrong indexes (maybe those of the proxy?). I suggest you to edit the question and provide a valid and complete [mre] of your latest attempt, including the part where you try to set the filter.

Comment: I changed my post.